# getSupportFragmentManager() returns null

Tags: android, exception, tabs, fragment

So here's the code : 
Calling the SectionsPageradapter constructor :

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
```

The class SectionsPagerAdapter :

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_OBJECT, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the TabFragment class :

```
/**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLayout = R.layout.activity_file_list;
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLayout = R.layout.panel_view;
            break;

        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

So the error is that when I call mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter); it says that mSectionsPagerAdapter is null.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Nic

Comment: seems like you are calling `getSupportFragmentManager` at wrong place ...

Comment: I call it in my onCreate() function at the beggining

Comment: `mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());` is in `onCreate` of `Activity`? **after** `super.onCreate()` is called ?

Comment: what you are importing for fragment. v4 or app.

Comment: post your activity code .

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Hop, got it, I shouldve imported ...FragmentActivity too, idk it didnt give me an error though! Thanks :)

Comment: Please consider posting the answer as an answer - and marking it as the selected answer.